# WPF Doesn't show any image..why?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm creating a program and here's basically all of it's code. The idea is simple, when someone clicks on button_ok_Click, i want to show their name and photo(based on what numbers their have inserted). Every thing works fine on it, except of one thing that i had tried without success: Show a image from my database when someone clicks on button_ok_Click.
Thanks for the help.

```
<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="386" Margin="480,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="259" Source="{Binding Path=ImageFunc, Converter={StaticResource BinaryImageConverter}}"/>



namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class FuncionarioDAO : IFuncionarioDAO
    {
        private DbConnection conn;
        private Exception erro;
        private string sql;

        public FuncionarioDAO()
        {

            try
            {
                this.conn = DAOConexaoFactory.getConexao(3, "TEST", "TEST");
            }
            catch
            {
                erro = DAOConexaoFactory.getErro();
            }

        }
        public Funcionario buscaFuncionario(string id)
        {
            Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario();

            sql = "SELECT CHAPA, NOME, IMAGEM FROM TABLE WHERE CHAPA='"+id+"'";

            try
            {
                // Cria Conexão Driver especifico
                DbCommand cmd = DAOConexaoFactory.getFactory().CreateCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Cria set de dados
                DbDataReader dados = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // Converte Decimal para Double para IBM DB2 e MSSQL
                if (dados.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dados.Read())
                    {
                        funcionario.Mat = dados.GetString(0);
                        funcionario.Nome = dados.GetString(1);
                        funcionario.ImageFunc = (byte[]) dados["IMAGEM"];
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Retorna erro
                erro = ex;
            }
            return funcionario; 
        }

        public bool insereFuncionario(Funcionario funcionario)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string getErro()
        {
            return erro.ToString();
        }


    }
}



namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class Funcionario
    {
        private string mat;
        private string nome;
        private byte[] imagemFunc;

        public Funcionario()
        {

        }
        public Funcionario(string mat)
        {
            this.mat = mat;
        }

        public Funcionario(string mat, string nome, byte[] imagemFunc)
        {
            this.mat = mat;
            this.nome = nome;
            this.imagemFunc = imagemFunc;

        }

        public string Mat { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageFunc { get; set; }

    }
}



namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "1";
        }

        private void button_2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "2";
        }

        private void button_3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "3";
        }

        private void button_4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "4";
        }

        private void button_5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "5";
        }

        private void button_6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "6";
        }

        private void button_7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "7";
        }

        private void button_8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "8";
        }

        private void button_9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "9";
        }

        private void button_0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "0";
        }

        private void button_erase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = "";
        }

        private void button_ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Funcionario funcionario = new FuncionarioDAO().buscaFuncionario(textBox.Text);
            textBox2.Text = funcionario.Nome.Substring(0,funcionario.Nome.IndexOf(" "));


        }
    }
}


    namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        class BinaryImageConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                    byte[] ByteArray = value as byte[];
                    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                    bmp.BeginInit();
                    bmp.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ByteArray);
                    bmp.EndInit();
                    return bmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Couple of things I am not sure you need to call cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() since you are calling cmd.ExecuteReader() directly after.  Your SQL is not an Update, Insert, Delete. No need for NonQuery.  Also use SQL Command Parameters instead of String concat for your SQL command.  Look up SQL injection as to why.  For your Image conversion, have you tried returning the Explicit BitmapImage type vs object?  Also are you properly setting the datacontext in your XAML so your Image control knows where to get ImageFunc.  Is this an MVVM project?

Comment: You are right, no need for ExecuteNonQuery() :D

here's my context 
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BinaryImageConverter x:Key="BinaryImageConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

Comment: About returning the explicit BitmapImage type..how can i say...this is my second day using c#, i'm a little lost but, it seems the database returns a "Image" data for me, what kind of variable should i use to get it?

Comment: I am referring to your Converter.  In your converter you have public object Convert, I am saying have you tried public BitmapImage Convert.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are using any type of MVVM so instead of doing a binding on your XAML in your button_ok_click you might need to set the Image Explicitly like  image1.Source = (convert byte array to BitmapImage here);  Or I think perhaps in your binding it would be {Binding Funcionario.ImageFunc} but you would need to make it a public property of your main window class and set it on your button_ok_click.

Answer (score 0):

You seem don't use View Model so you can set bitmap to your image directly:

```
private void button_ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Funcionario funcionario = new FuncionarioDAO().buscaFuncionario(textBox.Text);
    textBox2.Text = funcionario.Nome.Substring(0,funcionario.Nome.IndexOf(" "));

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(funcionario.ImageFunc))
    {
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.BeginInit();
        bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bmp.StreamSource = stream;
        bmp.EndInit();

        image.Source = bmp;
    }

    // If you don't see image, perhap your image is invalid
    // Save it to a file and open this file in Windows Explorer to check
    File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\img.jpg", funcionario.ImageFunc);
}
```

There is no need for IValueConverter here. You need to remove this from your image:

```
...Source="{Binding Path=ImageFunc, Converter={StaticResource BinaryImageConverter}}"...
```

By the way, your `BinaryImageConverter` lack of `ConvertBack` method. Are you cut it before post code here? Because if you don't have it, you code won't complie.

If you decide use View Model, you can do like this:

Add `ConvertBack` method to your `BinaryImageConverter`:

```
public class BinaryImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte[] ByteArray = value as byte[];
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(ByteArray))
        {
            bmp.BeginInit();
            bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bmp.StreamSource = stream;
            bmp.EndInit();
        }
        return bmp;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Set datacontext:

```
private void button_ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Funcionario funcionario = new FuncionarioDAO().buscaFuncionario(textBox.Text);
    DataContext = funcionario;
    // If textBox2.Text bind to Funcionario you can remove bellow line, move IndexOf to buscaFuncionario function
    textBox2.Text = funcionario.Nome.Substring(0,funcionario.Nome.IndexOf(" "));
}
```

Finally, you should not use String.Concat for database query, as @Bearcat9425 said.